# How get the data of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select

I am using this plugin:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree/

[image]

I won't get the id of that how can I do it.?

there no proper documentation available for this. is there any approach i can get it.?

```
<input type="text" id="justAnotherInputBox"
 placeholder="Type to filter" ng-change="showSummery(this)"/>



$scope.showSummery = function (data) {
        console.log(data)
};
```

Comment: what do you want to do with id?

Comment: i want the selected feild data whatever it has right now it has `id,title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an onclick listener on the `<li>` below the `<input>`:

```
$('#justAnotherInputBox')
    .parents('div.comboTreeWrapper')
    .find('div.comboTreeDropDownContainer')
    .on('click','li.ComboTreeItemChlid',function() {
   var id=$(this).find('span').attr('data-id');
   /* the rest of your code */
});
```

Note the typo "ComboTreeItemChlid". It is also in the plugin.

Comment: Onload its working, but when i change value its not coming.

Comment: Are you sure that you define the listener after you have defined the comboTreeWrapper?

Comment: Same for me not working after onchange.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1wkfo1i There is my html tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
 <input type="text" id="justAnotherInputBox"
     placeholder="Type to filter" ng-change="showSummery()"/>



    $scope.showSummery = function () {
            console.log(document.getElementById("justAnotherInputBox").value)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used bottom code to define combo tree:

```
    var comboTree2;
 comboTree2 = $('#justAnotherInputBox').comboTree({
        source: dataJson,
        isMultiple: false
    });
```

then you can used bottom code to get selected value id:

```
comboTree2._selectedItem.id
```